# Find an unknown number with the least amount of tries

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, math

I'm trying to code a python script that finds an unknown number with the least amount of tries possible.

All I know is the number is < 10000

Everytime I make a wrong input I get an "error" response.
When I find the right number I get a "success" response.

Let's assume in this case the number is 124.

How would you solve that in Python?

Thanks for helping. I'm really stuck on this one :(

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: That's called binary search algorithm : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: Binary search only helps if a miss tells you if you are above or below the number. As the question is written, we don't have this information. Only "hit" or "miss", nothing else. We have to try every number.

Comment: Is this a P = NP problem?

Comment: The problem is clearly in P, as the most naïve solution of trying all numbers is on `O(n)`, with `n` being the biggest number to try.

Comment: @DainDwarf Is there any other solution?

Comment: If instead of 'least amount of tries' you actually mean 'fastest' then you could possibly try testing multiple numbers in parallel.

Comment: Binary search is not possible cause it doesn't say if the number is above or below. But, is the "unknown number" generated randomly?

Answer (score 4):

If the number being `< 10000` is *all* you know, you have to try all numbers between `1` and `9999` (inclusive). The binary search algorithm as suggested in the comments does not help since a miss does not tell you if you are too high or too low.

```
for i in range(1, 10000):
    if i == number_you_are_looking_for:
        print("found it")
        break
```

Comment: I think this is the only possible solution.

Comment: Heh, slow day at the office.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the fastest way is to use binary search which gives the answer in O(log n).

```
def binary_search(n, min_value, max_value):
    tries = 0
    found = False

    if max_value < min_value:
        print("Maximum value must be bigger than the minimum value")
    elif n < min_value or n > max_value:
        print("The number must be between min_value and max_value")
    else:
        while min_value < max_value and not found:
            tries += 1

            mid_value = (min_value + max_value)//2

            if mid_value == n:
                found = True
            else:
                if n < mid_value:
                    max_value = mid_value - 1
                else:
                    min_value = mid_value + 1

            print([(min_value, max_value), (mid_value, n), tries])

        print("The number is:", str(n))
        print("Tries:", str(tries))
```

Examples:

```
binary_search(7, 0, 10)
>> The number is: 7
>> Tries: 2

binary_search(667, 0, 1000)
>> The number is: 667
>> Tries: 8

binary_search(2**19, 2**18, 2**20)
>> The number is: 524288
>> Tries: 19
```

Comment: So, in your particular case `binary_search(124, 0, 10000)` which gives the answer in 13 tries.

Comment: "But if you know the number, like in your case 124, I believe the fastest way is to use binary search" - can you please explain this logic?

Comment: Knowing the number makes it pointless to search for it. -1 for this answer.

Comment: @Alex.S Sure. Let's say that there's a small game where the number comes from the user input and then computer has to guess that number. Then binary search should be quite suitable and fast algorithm.

Comment: @Tichodroma How do we know your `number_you_are_looking_for` variable then?

Comment: I understand that. I don't understand the logical connection between "you know the number" and "the fastest way is binary search". Looking at your code I see that you provide the number to the function. So it makes no sense to use any search algorithm at all. You can immediately `print n` and that's it! Number of tries is zero and less is hardly possible ;)

Comment: The *program* knows it, else it can't judge if a try has been a hit or a miss. But the code *searching* for the number does *not* know it.

Comment: How is that different from `print number_you_are_looking_for`?
With my solution it'd be: `binary_search(number_you_are_looking_for, min_value, max_value)`

Comment: Reading the value from global variable or passing it as an argument doesn't change the fact that if the number is let us say 9000, binary search needs 750 times less guesses than checking all integers from 1 to 9000.